# Case insensitive array query Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a text array column in a Postgres table containing user's email and alt email addresses.

I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy and I want to query the database for the row where the user's inputed email is contained in the array. At the moment I'm using .contains

```
Users.query.filter(Users.emails.contains({email})).first()
```

The issue I'm having is that some of the existing email addresses have a mixture of upper and lower case however I can't seem to find a method for making an Array lower or the query case insensitive.

I've looked at func.lower but this doesn't want to play nicely with Arrays, the other option is .ilike however I can't seem to get this to work and my table is approx 10,000 rows and .ilike I don't think will be the most efficient?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A dirty solution would be to just cast the array to text, `lower()`, and check. Not very performance friendly, though. A cleaner approach is a bit more involved, but have a look at `unnest()` and [array constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS).

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thanks a lot for a pointer to `unnest()`!

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just using raw SQL, which did the trick.

```
db.engine.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE '%s' = ANY(lower(emails::text)::text[])" % email)
```

Comment: Though the solution works, -1 for string formatting values to queries. Use placeholders/bindparams: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql.